# install project visual studio 2010 files cannot be executed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a solution in visual studio with two project, windows service in .NET 4.0 and a GUI in .net 4.5 , i moved the service to .net 4.0 so i could use visual studio 2010 setup project and just move the files in setup.

The install process succeed but when i run the UI files the program crush , i find out that it's working if i run the UI as Administrator , but the project manifest does not require it and the compile files before the setup work fine and i need it to be able to run by any user, how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

So let me see if I understand - You tried to open your project in VS2010 instead of VS2012, to create a setup file, that requires an Admin Permission.
If so, you have to put this line in your manifest file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) thread can easily answer your question.

Comment: not quite , the service installed properly but i have a precompiled files that need to run without admin permission but now they require it